# Getting postgres error when trying to work with postgres large objects using node.js 'pg'

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg

Trying to execute `SELECT lo_creat(?)` using `pg.Client.query()` I'm getting error:
'syntax error at or near ")"'.

"node" 12.16.1, "pg" 8.0.2, "PostgreSQL" 12.0

```
const { Client } = require('pg'); 
...
const client = new Client({
  host: <host>,
  port: <port>,
  database: <database>,
  user: <user>,
  password: <password>,
});
await client.connect();
await client.query("SET SCHEMA '<schema>'"); // everything is fine
await client.query('SELECT lo_creat(?)', [0x00060000]); // throws the error here
...
```

Tried to execute the exact same query on my manual connection via pgAdmin4 and it worked fine returning the created `oid`.

Would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: In almost all cases "large objects" are the wrong choice to store binary data anyway. `bytea` is a much better choice. `lo_creat()` is a C function [provided by libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-interfaces.html#LO-CREATE)  the equivalent SQL function is called `lo_create()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is using wrong syntax to pass the parameters.

`$1` should be used instead of `?`.

`await client.query('SELECT lo_creat($1)', [0x00060000]);` works correct.